# Moving two agents together

Tags: anylogic

I am creating a model that includes both Material Handling and ABM components. I have an Agent Type that is called "Box" and there are 5 boxes that are placed on a conveyor in main. I have another Agent Type called "Product". The boxes are expected to carry the product. As a result, the box and product are expected to move on the conveyor as one. So, I was looking for something similar to move to agent, but that only works if the agent is not moving (i.e. it won't follow the agent everywhere it would just move to its position at the time the function is called). I can think of many solutions, none being ideal. Some include:

1. Not really moving the product agent, instead adding an animation shape of the product in the Box agent type and turn it on and off depending on the Product's state.
2. Using DES blocks (pickup/dropoff), but the problem with these is they convert the two agents to one... I am looking to keep both agents, but have them move together
3. Using something similar to Attach Resource, but then I'll have to define my Box or Product agent as a resource type

These are some of the solutions that came to mind, but I feel there must be a smoother solution. Any suggestions? Is there an ABM function that can resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I thought of an additional solution (not optimal). Use moveTo in an internal transition of type timeout that is happening every 0.01 seconds...

Comment: why do you need them to be independent if you need them to move as one? (using pickup) ... why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Pickup/Dropoff blocks retain both agents (with the picked-up one being contained within the picking-up one), so what is your issue with that approach? That seems precisely designed for this scenario: products contained within boxes on a conveyor.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I guess my main concern with Pickup/Dropoff is the animation. Only the container's animation shape becomes visible (as far as I know).

Comment: If you need an alternative animation whilst they're on the conveyor together (which suggests the product is not *in* the box on the conveyor!), why not just set one up for the container agent and make that visible whilst the pair are together on the conveyor?

Comment: Thank you for your input, I guess I will go with Pickup/Dropoff after all. I also discovered that nested Pickup/Dropoff works, so that was quite helpful. Thanks again!